# Texture scale problem for `collection instances` from `asset browser`

Tags: collections, asset-browser

Textures inside a `collection instance` I import through the `asset browser` have different scales when placed into the scene. The images attached are from the original file (where assets are) and the scene file. It is the same shader for all fabric objects.

The grid that is normally under the object is also not there as I drag the collection into the scene; but not sure if this is related to the mentioned problem.

[image: original objects]
[image: how the collections appear in the scene after they are imported]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was simple enough but easy to overlook. Some of the scales/transforms of several objects that made up the collections were not applied, which caused the problem. After applying everything; clearing and re-marking them as assets in the original file; erasing all assets from the new scene and loading them again they all imported correctly.